# jQuery validation plugin: apply one rule on all required fields

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery validation plugin for validation. I am using one javascript function for many forms so it is difficult to define rules for all fields for many forms.

What is the code if I want to apply a rule "required=true" for all textfields those have a class "required".

I am trying this but it is applying this rule only on first field. Remember I want to show images instead of error text  message when a field in not validated.

```
$(obj).find("input.required").rules("add", {

    required: true,
    minlength: 2,

    messages: {

        required : "<img id='exclamation' src='images/exclamation.gif' title='This field is required.' />",
        minlength: "<img id='exclamation' src='images/exclamation.gif' title='At least 2 characters.' />"

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the each function:

```
$(obj).find("input.required").each(function(){
  $(this).rules("add", {

        required: true,
        minlength: 2,

        messages: {

                required : "<img id='exclamation' src='images/exclamation.gif' title='This field is required.' />",
                minlength: "<img id='exclamation' src='images/exclamation.gif' title='At least 2 characters.' />"

        }
  });
});
```